# Consulta a base de datos MongoDB

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose

Quiero hacer una consulta a mi base de datos mongodb, usando la libreria mongoose. Pero hay un campo en un objeto que quiero que haga match con cualquier cosa. En contexto

```
const conditions = { 
service: serviceID,
address: { city: city, country: country, direction: /**Lo que sea*/} 
};

await serviceModel.find(conditions);
```

Como puedo hacer una consulta, de manera que direction haga match con cualquier valor?

Answer (score 0):

Se podría utilizar regex en el campo de búsqueda:

```
const conditions = { 
service: serviceID,
address: { 
    city: city, 
    country: country, 
    direction: new Regex("enrique","i") // Un ejemplo utilizando regex
  }  
};

await serviceModel.find(conditions);
```

Si las consultas son poca habituales y tu DB es pequeña podrías usar esta forma, pero si escalas y es tu DB aumenta te recomendaría utilizar indices de texto y realizar consultas con el operador `$search`. Te paso el link de MongoDB para que puedas ver como funciona [MongoDB: Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo estoy entendiendo bien, lo mejor en este caso es simplemente NO incluir `direction` en las condiciones de la Query, si te viene ya dado, haz una copia del objeto y elimina el campo:

```
const conditions = { 
  service: serviceID,
  address: { city: city, country: country, direction: /**Lo que sea*/} 
};

let no_dir_cond = Object.assign({}, conditions)
// La siguiente línea es para no modificar el objeto original en conditions.address
no_dir_cond.address = Object.assign({}, conditions.address)
delete no_dir_cond.address.direction;

await serviceModel.find(no_dir_cond);
```